# How to properly use sscanf in this context?

Tags: c, scanf, stdio

I have a **file** which structure is the following:

```
var1 2921
var2 0.5
var3 12
```

I need a **method** that gets the name of the file and 3 empty variables. It should **read the file and give a value for each variable**. (This is what I have tried so far)

```
void get_input(char * filename, int * var1, double * var2, int * var3){
    FILE *file;
    char buf[1024];
    file=fopen(filename,"r");
    if(file == NULL){
        printf("ERROR");
        exit(0);
    }

    int i=0;

    if(file){
        while(fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),file)!=NULL){    
            switch(i){
            case 0:
                sscanf(buf,"var1 %d",&var1);
                break;
            case 1:
                sscanf(buf,"var2 %f",&var2);
                break;
            case 2:
                sscanf(buf,"var3 %d",&var3);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

And the **main**:

```
int main()
{
    char filename[256];
    int var1,var3;
    double var2;

    snprintf(filename,256,"file.txt");

    get_input(filename,&var1,&var2,&var3);

    printf("%s %d","var1: ",var1);
    printf("%s %f","\nvar2: ",var2);
    printf("%s %d","\nvar3: ",var3);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> var1:  8
>
> var2:  0.000000
>
> var3:  2011837489

Comment: Why `buf[strlen(buf)-1]='\0';` ?

Comment: One problem is that you don't check the return value from `sscanf()` so you don't know when it fails.

Comment: Another is that if `fopen` fails, you will be reporting from uninitialised variables but no tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. For a double, you need to use `%lf`, not `%f`; in `scanf` as well as in `printf`. Alternatively, you could use `float`, that goes with `%f`.
2. You are passing the addresses of var1, 2, 3; so taking the address again in scanf is duplicate - you will get the address of the address.
   Use `var1` instead of `&var1` inside the `scanf`.

Comment: Note that `printf()` formats `double` with either `%f` (the classic notation) or `%lf` (the C99 or later notation).  The difference is crucial for the `scanf()` family, though.